# Memory Detection in ARM

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, arm

I am new to ARM and finding out ways to detect the memory map of platform based on ARM.Earlier I worked little in x86 and can find out memory map using some BIOS calls.

Same way can we do in ARM though BIOS is not there in ARM.

Is there any instruction do exist in ARM to find the Memory map ??

Comment: _"though BIOS is not there in ARM"_. Some ARM-based devices have BIOSes. It's not really dependent on which CPU architecture you're using.

Comment: You can start looking for it in the CPU datasheet(technical reference manual)

Comment: What operating system? Or you're writing one yourself?

Comment: Just for learning purpose and I am booting Linux kernel on my ARM based platform.

Answer (score 4):

How do I find the memory map for an ARM CPU guide:

1. Read the documentation from arm.com for your coresponding core
2. Read the documentation of your CPU
3. Read the documentation of your platform, to see if it has external memory connected to SOC(CPU)

Or as a shortcut:
If your platform vendor provides a toolchain to compile code for it, make a dummy project and look for the memory layout in you linker file...

Gather this information:

1. Memory map for the corresponding core
2. Memory map of your CPU
3. If it has external accessible memory you have to perform some steps to initialize the controller.
4. Use gathered data and build the linker file for you project
5. Do whatever you want with it

Comment: +1 which is pretty much the same way on any other platform including x86.

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface as ubiquitous as BIOS or EFI for ARM systems, though Microsoft does specify UEFI for systems that run Windows.

The Linux boot interface is the most common interface, see Documentation/arm/Booting in the kernel source and the header files.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write a program that to be portable across different Arm devices, you have to detect the memory by yourself. I am not very good especially in ARM, but there are common principles - you simply can scan the whole address space and probe the memory by writing a number and then reading it back. Usually, two such operations are provided with different numbers in order to exclude the occasional mistakes:

```
1. write 0aah
2. read and check for 0aah
3. write 055h
4. read and check for 055h
```

Note 1: for better speed not every byte have to be checked - some natural granularity have to be used and to check only at the start of the pages (whatever size are on this platform).

At the end you will have a map for the RAM memory. The ROM memory is not so easy to be detected, though and there is no common solution.

Note 2: Depending on the architecture (well, I said I am not ARM expert) your program must have access to the whole memory, according to the memory protection mechanisms of the CPU (if any).

Note 3: The only possible problem with this approach is the memory mapped IO. Touching it can affect the IO devices in unpredictable way. That is why, you must know what area of the addressing space is used for memory mapped IO and not to test it at all.

Comment: this solution can lead to a hang, not very reliable.

Comment: This solution can't lead to hang. And it is not invented by me. And it is widely used.

Comment: You could also accidentally write invalid values into memory mapped I/O ports in the address space. I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: If you touch an address space that is not used by the chip vendor then all bets are off it can and will hang it happens quite often on arm and many other platforms.  If you already know where memory because you looked it up then why are you detecting, you already know the answer?

Comment: I am agree about the memory mapped IO and added a note about it in the answer. But I am not agree about the empty address space. Trying to read/write to missing memory can not harm the CPU at all. At least I can't see any mechanism how such operation can harm the CPU.